# Can I say "which of whom"?

Tags: relative-clauses

Would you teach me if the following phrase is grammatically and semantically correct? if so, when you would rather use it? in which situation?

What is more, is it a formal or informal phrase? I failed find such a phrase in Google books!

***which of whom***

Comment: Where did you find this phrase? Can you provide a sentence? Native speakers know many contexts in which it can be used, but do you? We cannot teach you if it is correct without seeing how it is used.

Comment: The phrase sounds very awkward - "whom" means "to who", so really this sounds like "which one of to who", and I can't make sense of it. "which of them", "which one", or simply "who" might be more appropriate, but to @δοῦλος's point, please provide a few example sentences in which you'd use that expression.

Comment: @RuslanD "Whom" does **not** mean "to who". "Whom" is an [object pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pronoun), while "who" is a [subject pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_pronoun).

Comment: @Kreiri good point, I was thinking of it being, historically, the dative case of "who" and representing that as "to who", but you're a lot more correct w.r.t. what an ELL should actually know.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever said *which of whom* in my entire life, nor have I ever read it until I ngrammed it just now.

Comment: nima,  Is "each of whom" appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Which** can be used both as a determiner as well as a pronoun. As a pronoun it can refer to a person as well.

**Example -**

> 1. A couple of women...**one of which**..leaned on other's shoulder.
> 2. He had nine wives, **all which** he cast of successively.

**SOURCE <sub>OED</sub> -**

[image]

**of** here is **used to show somebody/something belongs to a group.**
<sub>**SOURCE -** Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary</sub>

**Example -**

> 1. The most famous **of** all the stars.
> 2. Some **of** his friends.

**whom** is a pronoun. The accusative form of **who**. It refers back to a person or a group of people.

So the phrase - **which of whom** - refers to those from a group of people.

**Example -**

> 1. Other finalists, **each which of whom** interviewed in public here in November, were Natasha Henderson, city manager/chief administrative officer for the city of Muskegon Heights. [**each which of whom** refers to each one from those finalists]
> 2. One classic example is that at the immigration office you may be asked to prove, by way of a document from the land registry (tulajdonilap), that the person you’re renting from is indeed the owner, is perhaps not just one of multiple owners, **any which of whom** might have the right to throw you out into the street because they didn’t sign up to you living there. [**any which of whom** refers to any owner from those multiple owners]
> 3. Not the hard working people of America **which of whom** pay taxes. [**which of whom** refers to the ones from those people who work hard]

I believe the natural and frequently used wordings would be **each one of whom** (in sentence #1), **any one of whom** (in sentence #2) and only **who** (in sentence #3)

**N.B -** I haven't found much example sentences of **which of whom**, and those found in Google books are mostly from old texts. So my hunch is that it's a old usage, still alive in some dialects, or in some English speaking regions. Though I have no evidence to prove my thought. It's just my assumption.

Comment: Many thanks all. I agree with all. I was wrong comprehensively.

Answer (score 0):

The string `'which of whom'` is too archaic to be consider *valid* today.

I found two instances in Google Books.

[Beverlac: Or, The Antiquities and History of the Town of Beverley, in the County of York](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=mgcIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA547&lpg=PA547&dq=%22which%20of%20whom%22&source=bl&ots=B_ewFde00W&sig=gNRbIRyFyWWTHbaOr2gFgPdq2Sc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Bnb-VN_IHJWhugSo5oHwDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22which%20of%20whom%22&f=false) -

> *"**which of whom** shall be thereunto first required"*

Check out, even *['thereunto'](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thereunto)* is archaic.

Another example in a historical book -[The Charters of the Town of Kingston Upon Thames](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nB0wAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA158&dq=%22which%20of%20whom%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nHn-VOb7IJG_uAS-44LYAg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22which%20of%20whom%22&f=false) 
(translated)

> *"...the election was to be made, nor before **which of whom** any who should be respectively chosen into...."*

I think it's better not to use it and stick to simpler form of 'of who' or 'of which'.

Comment: Yes the phrase does seem odd to me too. The google book hit that you quoted doesn't make any sense to me. But I think there is nothing wrong with that phrase. I found some news containing that phrase and that perfectly makes sense.

Comment: Please cite that news, Man_From_India, if you would.

Comment: @TRomano I deleted my post, because many people think that phrase might be a typo. There is no hit in COCA, though I don't believe if there is no hit in online corpus the phrase is wrong. But when native speakers aren't comfortable with it, then there is reason of thinking that it's wrong. Well I will undelete my answer, for you to see some quotations I found in online news articles :-)

Comment: Thanks. "each which of whom" should be either *each of which* or *each of whom* and "any which of whom" should be *any of whom*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be used, colloquially, in the obscure situation when you're requesting explanation of two words at once in a specific context.

> "That guy was firfteenth of swermers in the nathonal shampoonships of 1997."
>
> "Don't talk with your mouth full. Swallow, and then tell me again, that guy was **which of whom** in the national championships of 1997?"
>
> *gulp* "Thirteenth of swimmers!"

Answer (score 0):

We don't find the phrase "which of whom" in grammar books. Grammar books do speak of many of whom, most of whom, few of whom, several of whom, etc., but there is no mention of which of whom.  Besides, as commented above, the native speaker doesn't use this phrase. It will, therefore, be odd and unnatural to use the phrase.